# Microsoft IIS 7.5 ftp ssl problem

Tags: iis, ssl, ftp

I have configured IIS 7.5 ftp service to use SSL. I have two environments (one for testing purposes, without ssl). When we activate SSL users can logon and list and get files maybe one time if there lucky, then the host (service?) becomes unreachable for some reason. I have no idea what happens  or why the FTP "locks" it self. When the ftp is in the "locked" state i am still able to telnet the ftp service, but login do not work.

The test environment without SSL works perfectly and never locks itself. I have also tried turning off SSL on the production environment and that makes that environment work perfectly too.

So the problem must be with SSL (certificate is from versisign). Have someone experienced the same problem och now what can be the cause of this?

/ Tommy

Comment: Should be moved to serverfault

Answer (score 0):

See [this document](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/)

Specifically these sections:

- Using Windows Firewall with secure FTP over SSL (FTPS) traffic
- More Information about Working with Firewalls

(At the bottom)